# Read Committed Snapshot Isolation and Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am considering enabling Read Committed Snapshot Isolation on our SQL 2005 database in an attempt to gain some performance. Does setting this isolation level effect all queries regardless of whether they are using BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN? According to MSDN:

"Once snapshot isolation is enabled, updated row versions for each transaction are maintained in tempdb."

I am unclear if "transaction" means all sql queries or only queries explicitly using transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Every* (useful) statement runs within a transaction. If there isn't an open one when you run a particular query, then by default SQL Server opens one, runs the query, and then commits it. This is called [Autocommit mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This behaviour can be changed so that it doesn't do that third step automatically (the commit) and leaves the transaction open. That's called [Implicit Transaction Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: So I can use RCSI even if my queries arent using implicit transactions?